# Python - Import Client Module

Tags: python, dropbox, raspberry-pi

I am new with python. Today I am trying to connect my raspberry pi to dropbox.
I followed this tutorial http://cttoronto.com/03/16/2013/raspberry-pi-dropbox-sync/.
I used the `cli_client.py` as example and inserted my app ids etc.

```
import cmd
import locale
import os
import pprint
import shlex

from dropbox import client, rest, session


APP_KEY = "XXX"
APP_SECRET = "XXX"

ACCESS_TYPE = "Full Dropbox"

sess = session.DropboxSession(APP_KEY,APP_SECRET,ACCESS_TYPE)

request_token = sess.obtain_request_token()

url = sess.build_authorize_url(request_token)
```

Then i tried executing the script but got the following error (`sudo python cli_client.py`):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cli_client.py", line 7, in <module>
    from dropbox import client, rest, session
  File "/var/tmp/setuptools/dropbox-python-sdk-1.5.1/example/dropbox.py", line 7, in <module>
    from dropbox import client, rest, session
ImportError: cannot import name client
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: import dropbox; print dir(dropbox);

Answer (score 1):

The script is looking in the "dropbox" module for the 'client' - as you can see from the error. Either you haven't installed it properly or the tutorial's wrong (yes, see below).

Did you make sure to download the Dropbox module and install it. The tutorial has a typo in it and you should run:

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-python-sdk-1.5.1.zip
```

To download the dropbox file and to create the module.

Even easier would be to install the Dropbox module using either `easy_install` or `pip`*. Try the following:

```
sudo pip install dropbox
```

---

For extra-advanced usage, get to know virtualenv and virtualenv-wrapper so you don't install hundreds of modules all over the place... but that's a bit outside the scope of this question for now ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You should first properly install the dropbox package.

Checkout [*pip*](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/) or [*easyinstall*](http://pythonhosted.org/distribute/easy_install.html).

After installing the dropbox package using

```
sudo easy_install dropbox
```

or

```
sudo pip install dropbox
```

the package should most likely reside in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dropbox/`

Then running the above code from outside `/var/tmp/setuptools/dropbox-python-sdk-1.5.1/example` should not return the aforementioned error.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error closely, you can see that there is a dropbox import statement in a file called "dropbox.py" which causes a namespace conflict.

```
  File "cli_client.py", line 7, in <module>
    from dropbox import client, rest, session
  File "/var/tmp/setuptools/dropbox-python-sdk-1.5.1/example/dropbox.py", line 7, in <module>
    from dropbox import client, rest, session
ImportError: cannot import name client
```

Just rename the .py file to something like foo.py, and you are good to go on that import.  But it looks like this problem was fixed in a subsequent release of the api.

I got bitten by this problem when I first started playing with the dropbox api, and placed my code into a "dropbox.py" file.  ;)